# getting list items in SPFx application

Tags: sharepoint

trying to retrieve list items via get method of spHttpClient object in SPFx webpart project.

Here code piece;

```
private readItems(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: 'Loading all items...',
      items: []
    });
    this.props.httpClient.get(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`, 
    SPHttpClientConfigurations.v1)
      .then((response: Response): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
        debugger;
        return response.json();
      });
  }
```

when this function triggered here is the response from server; 
[image]

Message is obvious, but I really need to get list items in this web address. how can I achieve it ?

I created this project with yeoman generator("yo @microsoft/sharepoint") is there any configuration to make it run http:// instead of https://

as you know default address of application is "https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to access the tenant, if you do not deploy it. If you  deploy it to SharePoint, that will link your workbench with SharePoint.

Another option is that, you can to mock your list if you will use the local workbench instead of the SharePoint tenant.

You can have a look at this video on how to mock your list or deploy it to SharePoint:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VMwjb2pbQ8&index=3&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXvSWvS2zglCzz4iplhVrKq

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use your tenant's workbench: https://your_tenant_name.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

In this case you don't need to mock anything. 
Just use gulp serve --nobrowser and go to that url.